# Why is an observeEvent of a button is triggered falsely (the second time)?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I have written a small module that shows a modal dialog box. The user selects values using the dialog box and then clicks a button to confirm. These values are then passed to the application that called the module in the first place.

When I run the module the first time, it completes as desired. The second time I run it, the confirmation button within the module gets clicked automatically (also, the values chosen are reset).
When I run the module for the third time, it completes as desired. On the fourth time the strange behavior is continued. And so on.

Minimal reprex below.

The application :

```
library(shiny)

source("condSelectModule2.R")

ui <- fluidPage(
  condSelectUI("chooseCond"),
  actionButton("makeChoice", "Choose"),
  textOutput("showCond")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$makeChoice,  {
               r <- condSelectServer("chooseCond", c(1,2,3))
  
               output$showCond <- renderText(unlist(r()))             
  })
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The module :

```
condSelectUI <- function(id) {}

condSelectServer <- function(id, conds)
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    
    ns <- session$ns
    
    showModal(modalDialog(
      title="Select a number",
      footer=tagList(     fluidRow(
        selectInput(ns("Number"), "Select a number", choices=conds)
      ),
      actionButton(ns("goBtn"), "Ok")
      )))
    
    
    observeEvent(input$goBtn,  {
        print(c(input$Number))
        removeModal()
      }
    )
    
    
    # return value
    
    reactive(input$Number)
    
  })
```

Comment: My feeling is that the way I call the module is flawed.

Comment: where is `condSelectUI`?

Comment: @PorkChop Added, thanks. It is an empty function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option `ignoreInit = TRUE` should work.  Try this

```
observeEvent(input$goBtn,  {
      print(c(input$Number))
      removeModal()
}, ignoreInit = TRUE)
```